# Call nested component function angular2

Tags: angular

Imagine this Host Component code:

```
@Component({
    directives: [nestedComponentDirective]
})

export class ParentComponent {
     save():void {
            this.myService.myHTTPCall().subscribe((event) => {
                // if callback successfull we need to let directive know
            })
        }
```

Now the Nested Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'someSelector',
  template: `
  <div>
    <button [stuff]="stuff"</button>
  </div>`
})


export class ContinuationCheckDirective {
  @Input() waitingForHostedComp(value) {
    console.log ("value", value)
  }
```

How to call waitingForHostedComp from the Host-Component (Parent)?

Comment: Please provide more code. Where is `save()` and `waitingForHostComp()`?

Comment: `save()` is on ParentComponent importing the ChildComponent. `waitingForHostComp()` is on ChildComponent. Basically what I want is a listener on the ChildComponent that gets triggered when the ParentComponent (which injects the ChildComponent) gets an answer from the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you can do it is using `ViewChild`, i.e., we inject the child component into the parent as a `ViewChild`.

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: ` implements AfterViewInit
  <child-component></child-component>
  `,
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent)
  private childComponent: ChildComponent;

  save(): void {
        this.myService.myHTTPCall().subscribe((event) => {
            this.childComponent.waitingForHostedComp(event);
        })
  }

}
```

You can see more details in the [Component Interaction Cookbook: Parent Calls a ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child).

Comment: Interesting.... will my other Inputs and Outputs work (I did not cite that in this code sample) as before?

Comment: Absolutely, they'll work as before. ViewChild is just a way to interact with you child component in the typescript code.

Comment: I had to put `private childComponent: ChildComponent;` into the constructor, and then it works perfectly. Thank you, Bernardo.

Comment: I'm glad to help @StephanKristyn!